# Android structuring / naming of classes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, android-studio

Im am struggling a little with how to name classes and where to put them. I wonder how others deal with this.

Example, ik have classes like:

- PersonEntity (relates to the datamodel)
- PersonActivity
- PersonFragment
- PersonAdapter

Somehow it lokes nice, because all classes related to Person are grouped. But when working in a large app it does not feel structured enough as all class files are within one big list.

The same question regarding layout files. I would like to nicely group Activity, Fragment and list-items files.

Can somebody show me how you structure / name all classes within a large app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I work, is that I add packages like 'fragments', 'model', 'adapters', ... So PersonAdapter would go in the 'adapters' package, and so on. My layout files all go in the same directory but are kind of grouped by their name. For example, the layout file for PersonFragment would be called fragment_person.xml. The layout file for PersonActivity will be called activity_person.xml. List items are list_item_person.xml.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you adding those packages into the 'java' directory? Or one level lower, into the com.mycompany.myapplication package? I hope somebody else also would like to share their ways.

Comment: @Brabbeldas I'm adding those one level lower, in the myapplication package.